# maven-exec-plugin - npm run build - error: The build command requires to be run in an Angular project

Tags: docker, maven, npm

I wrote a Maven app (running in Docker container) which compiles Angular app.
In pom.xml I have near the end:

```
[...]
<execution>
    <id>npm run build</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
    <configuration>
            <executable>npm</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>run</argument>
                        <argument>build:hello</argument>
                    </arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>    
[...]
```

In package.json I have

```
"build:hello": "ng build hello --base-href /hello --deploy-url /hello/static/ --prod && cd ./projects/hello-app && gulp tasks --base-href=/hello --deploy-url=/hello/static/",
```

In local environment it works

On Docker fails with this error

```
The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
```

The current working directory is /

In / folder I have:

```
[...]
pom.xml
package.json
package-lock.json
node_modules
angular.json
/projects/hello-app
[...]
```

All the previous npm commands works (npm ci, npm install,..)

Any suggests?

Comment: I would suggest to use [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) instead of manually handling that via exec-maven-plugin...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Crazy.
For some unknown reason the folder / (root) doesn't work
I copied all the stuff under /app and ran npm build from there and it works!

Make no sense, in my opinion